# How to increase emission strength when a property value is reached with logic bricks? (UPBGE)

Tags: animation, shaders, game-engine, keyframes, shader-nodes

I have a game where I collect coins, which are counted using a game integer property. Is there a way of increasing the emission of a character upon reaching 10 coins? I tried keyframing emission as an animation to link this in, but the inserted keyframes did not show in action editor for me to make an animation of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Logic-Bricks`

### Information

You can create a keyframe action with most UI elements by clicking the diamand-shaped icon near an UI element:

[image]

Which should than automatically create an animation Action which you can select as an animation to play in an Action actuator:

[image]

I also setup a sync/driver setup for the keyframed Action with a created integer game-property I called <kbd>Emission</kbd>:

### Emission property value of <kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]

### Emission property value of <kbd>10</kbd>:

[image]

### Download

Download the blend here:

https://github.com/RandomPandaStudios/BSE-Blend-Storage/blob/main/UPBGE_03_Dynamic_Emission.blend

## `Python`

Remember, BPY works at runtime in **UPBGE +0.3**.

### Code

`Material_Name` should be the name of the emissive material.
`inputs[1]`, if the shader node is type emission, should be the attribute: `Strength`.

```
import bpy 

bpy.data.materials["Material_Name"].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 10.0
```

Enabling `Python Toolips` in your User Prefences is a great way to easily and quickly see what BPY code is required for a certain element.

[image]

Comment: Hello Panda, the confusion was more to do with keyframes not working on my particular character, but thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: Were you able to keyframe your character eventually?

Comment: For some reason it works on simple objects but not on my character, perhaps because it is connected to an armature. Is there a way to boost emission via python script? Because then I can use logic bricks to say "If in this state/under this property - then script = active" (I would send the file but I want to keep my game features private till release). Thanks.

Comment: @EmreTurk: Then you should provide your blend file (or a simplified one), so we can check it out...

Comment: I have replicated the shaders on this object. Keyframes show an effect on the timeline but are not visible, hence animations cannot be made. Any ideas?                            [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zr94V34l" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zr94V34l/)

Comment: Added Python code + information in my original post. Side note, when I opened your blend file, I saw 0 keyframes. Maybe it's on my end and I need to upgrade to UPBGE 0.31 instead of using my 0.3 version.

Comment: Thank you Paladin, this is just what I was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could help!